# Very unusual error that I have never seen. UNITY

Tags: unity-game-engine, 3d

Im getting this weird error that I have never seen before and i have like 400 of them and they i think are all different. Here is an example Library\PackageCache\com.unity.test-framework@1.1.20\UnityEngine.TestRunner\NUnitExtensions\Runner\UnityTestExecutionContext.cs(125,34). This also happened right after my pc shorted out. I fixed it loaded up unity and all my files were gone. I was planning on trying to redo some of my stuff when this came up. I'm also having a warning about a meta data file existing but its packages cant be found. I don't know if these are connected or not. This is also a brand new project so its not anything old.

Comment: UPDATE: its literally happening on every SINGLE project i make. I just want to make a game ;(

Comment: UPDATE 2: https://www.reddit.com/r/Unity3D/comments/hxkx5v/unity_test_framework_errors_on_projects/ can anybody help me find the file to delete?

Answer (score 1):

Answer: Go to your library and you will find all your projects and such there. If you locate to the project you are currently working on find a folder called package cache. Delete this and you will have no more errors!

Comment: actually don't just delete the whole folder if your not just starting out the project just delete the files that show in the erros